# submit form inside a href link html

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Please help me in my case, i case 3 submit buttons who submit different values, but for me need to change submit form to simply link a href html, who do the same, how i can do this?

There is my submit forms:

```
<input type="submit" value="2" maxlength="1" name="post_request">
<input type="submit" value="3" maxlength="1" name="post_request">
<input type="submit" value="4" maxlength="1" name="post_request">
```

P.S. How to send only submit form, it's not a problem, problem how to send the submit with name and value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="someurl?post_request=2">value 2</a>
```

is the equivalent of

```
<form method="GET" ACTION="someurl">
  <input type="submit" value="2" maxlength="1" name="post_request">
</form>
```

if you want to use `POST` type you'll need to populate some hidden input using javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery you can do `$('input[value="2"]').submit()` and I'd suggest adding the value as a hidden input.

Comment: yes thanks, it's a good idea, but how to set this variable, and set the name post_request?

Comment: Can you do 3 separate buttons and an ajax call instead? It would probably be a lot easier, since a submit puts only params of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I will have the link call a javascript function. The function does the post. It's kind of lengthy... Porbably there's better way to do it.

```
<a href="javascript:DoSubmit(2)">post_request</a>
<a href="javascript:DoSubmit(3)">post_request</a>
<a href="javascript:DoSubmit(4)">post_request</a>

<script>
function DoSubmit(val) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var send_str = "val=" + val;
  xhr.open('POST', '', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", send_str.length);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
     document.open();
     document.write(xhr.responseText);
     document.close();
     }
  };
  xhr.send(send_str);
}
</script>
```